# Close keyboard by swiping in Flutter

Tags: flutter

In Flutter, I want the keyboard to close when I scroll from top to bottom on the screen while the keyboard is open. Can you help me on this issue?

I tried TextField's auto focus feature but it didn't work. Help me please

Answer (score 1):

```
onTapOutside: (event) => FocusScope.of(context).unfocus(),
```

Add Following line in TextField widget

Comment: It worked, it works 